# Fill a column with start number to end number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Let's say in A1 I have the number 500 and in A45 I have the number 323.

How do fill cells A2->A44 with numbers that evenly reduce down to the end number of 323 (A45)?

Comment: If by "number" you mean integers, there is no sequence that "evenly" reduces down that way, because the step required between values is about `4.023`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the step, find the difference between `A1` and `A45` and divide that by the number of rows between the two cells plus 1.

Then multiply the step by the sequence 1, 2, 3... N where N is the number of rows between the two cells, and subtract the product from `A1`, like this:

`=arrayformula( A1 - sequence(rows(A2:A44)) * ((A1 - A45) / (rows(A2:A44) + 1) ) )`

To get *integers* that will at various steps be one larger or smaller than others, add `round()`, like this:

`=arrayformula( round( A1 - sequence(rows(A2:A44)) * ((A1 - A45) / (rows(A2:A44) + 1) ) ) )`

Answer (score 0):

- go to **File**
- select **Spreadsheet settings**
- choose **Calculation**
- and turn on **Iterative calculation**
- then use this formula:

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), )))+SORT(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-2)), 1, 0)*(A1-INDIRECT("A"&
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))))/(
 MAX(IF(A3:A<>"", ROW(A3:A), ))-1))
```

[image]

Comment: #between numbers