# Google Sheet gradually grow number over X cells with growth graph

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two constants:
Initial number: 20
Final number 1300

In Google Sheet, I want to gradually increase from 20 to 1300 over 12 cells (A1 to J1).

I have this formula: `=A1 * ((1300 / 20)^(1/11))` but the increase per cell will be: `20    9   13  20  29  42  62  90  131 192 281 411`

There are two issues:

1. It doesn't take into account the initial number. It looks like we dip from 20 to 9 and then start growing
2. I am looking for a way to control the "curve" of the exponential growth.

To illustrate the growth I am looking for, here is an image of a growth graph where you can see the number initially growing slowly, and gaining momentum with time. (ignore the actual number I added in there, it's just for demonstration purposes)

[image: Exponential growth graph]

What formula would you suggest?

Comment: Ben, to be honest I do have a formula for you to achieve this in 12 cells. Using Exponential Growth Factor. However the second requirements you have the acceleration and declaration do you have a more specific information about this, as this falls as qualitative description and really vague when being incorporated to your question. Do you have a definite growth factor, which points will it happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill a column with start number to end number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73432777/fill-a-column-with-start-number-to-end-number)

Comment: The answer by @doubleunary in [Fill a column with start number to end number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432869/1330560) seems suited to your question. Adjusted for A1-J1 = Cell B2:`=transpose(arrayformula( round( A1 - sequence(columns(B1:I1)) * ((A1 - J1) / (columns(B1:I1) + 1) ) ) ))`

Comment: @Babanana I added a visual graph to better illustrate what I'm after.

Comment: @Tedinoz the question you referenced and the solutions show a way to create a constant growth and not exponential as far as I could see.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I went ahead and wrote a formula to achieve this type of growth:
`=TRANSPOSE(A4 * EXP(LN($B$2 / $B$1) * (COLUMN(B$4:$I4) - COLUMN(A4)) / (COLUMNS(B4:I4))))`

And here it is on Google Sheet:

[image: Exponential growth]

This solution works, but is it possible to add a growth factor so that I can initially grow faster?

Comment: You must first identify which points and requirements for your growth factors, it must be really specific in order for you to define it. The growth factor you might be worth considering is Exponential Decay, if you want to consider something that is closer to an average, what you are Looking is Linear Growth Factor and not Exponential.